# Convert Range of Cells to Python Dictionary

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a 5 column table in excel wherein I want each row in the left-most column ('A' or 0) to be the key and the 4 subsequent columns on that row to be the values.

so far I have:

```
call_data = CallData.to_dict()
call_data.index('A').to_dict(orient='index')
print(call_data)
```

This makes each column header the key and all rows below (28) values. Any way to change this? I have googled my heart out.

This is what the table looks like for 28 rows. Column A is the the one I want to be the key.

```
A     | B      |C      |D       |E 
Jan-15| 800    |6.47   |530,000 |1.6
```

**EDIT 3**:

I get this (NEW) error when running code now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Personal Files/Technical Development/PycharmProjects/Call Center Headcount Model/Call Center Headcount Model.py", line 52, in <module>
    dict_result = call_data.set_index('A').to_dict(orient='index')
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\Enviroment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4303, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['A'] are in the columns"
```

Code:

```
    SpreadSheetData = pd.read_excel(
    FilePath + 'Call Center Work Rules.xlsx',
    sheet_name='Data Agg.')

    call_data = SpreadSheetData
    dict_result = call_data.set_index('A').to_dict(orient='index')
```

this is what the data Fram Prints to exaclty: Print(SpreadSheetData)

```
    Date    Calls  AVG Call Time  Total Call Time        Orders
0  2015-01-31  82034.0       6.471024    530843.967784  1.633581e+06
1  2015-02-28  78007.5       6.743146    526015.928294  6.534326e+05
2  2015-03-31  84425.5       6.608714    557943.983912  9.801489e+05
3  2015-04-30  71089.0       6.959075    494713.692979  8.478081e+05
4  2015-05-31  77414.0       6.732396    521181.717775  1.186931e+06
5  2015-06-30  86811.0       6.999769    607656.979210  1.356493e+06
6  2015-07-31  81995.0       7.051137    578157.977305  1.861042e+06
7  2015-08-31  62538.0       7.995746    500037.935402  1.116625e+06
8  2015-09-30  45677.5       7.885182    360175.378283  7.444169e+05
9  2015-10-31  52542.0       8.083627    424729.950838  1.000827e+06
10 2015-11-30  51352.0       7.608637    390718.717376  1.751447e+06
11 2015-12-31  58871.0       7.675463    451862.183771  2.251861e+06
12 2016-01-31  68664.0       7.745629    531845.879620  1.712810e+06
13 2016-02-29  74043.5       7.937032    587685.592567  6.851241e+05
14 2016-03-31  77155.0       8.221454    634326.306777  1.027686e+06
15 2016-04-30  60979.5       8.059682    491475.397091  8.889268e+05
16 2016-05-31  69163.0       7.885619    545393.085653  1.244498e+06
17 2016-06-30  90276.0       8.508960    768154.893931  1.422283e+06
18 2016-07-31  90854.5       8.506498    772853.621003  1.951303e+06
19 2016-08-31  72722.5       7.479822    543951.323850  1.170782e+06
20 2016-09-30  54339.0       7.215742    392096.181983  7.805211e+05
21 2016-10-31  68084.0       7.705519    524622.580078  1.049367e+06
22 2016-11-30  58564.0       7.066731    413856.014456  1.836393e+06
23 2016-12-31  63573.0       7.420257    471727.986085  2.361076e+06
24 2017-01-31  71665.5       7.527221    539442.083982  1.796311e+06
25 2017-02-28  62583.5       7.295476    456576.395666  7.185243e+05
26 2017-03-31  76385.5       7.317654    558962.634577  1.077786e+06
27 2017-04-30  69727.5       7.330732    511153.636251  9.322625e+05
28 2017-05-31  81249.5       7.247624    588865.803177  1.305168e+06
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a dict such that ```{'Jan-15': [800, 6.47, 530000, 1.6]}```? And knowing that you have multiple rows, you will have them in a list like ```[{'Jan-15': [800, 6.47, 530000, 1.6}], { ...}]```?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to be able to access a certain value from each key when necassary and thought this to be the optimal way. Also i should clarify the "CallData" is the worksheet accessed through pandas

Comment: So the ```CallData``` is supposed to be a dataframe already. Can you try ```CallData.set_index('A').to_dict(orient='index')```?

Comment: Just edited the post. Got another error.

Comment: You might want to print that CallData prior to setting the index, just to make sure it is ok. Could you print some of the dataframe?

Comment: I edited my post to show the print and make variable names less ambiguous. Still getting an error that I put up there.

Comment: ```set_index('Date')``` because your column is named Date, not A

Comment: Have you tried replacing the column name "A" with the column you actually want to use "Date"?

Comment: That worked!. Thank you @Andondraif Really appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict_result = call_data.set_index('A').to_dict(orient='index')
```

Example:

```
call_data = pd.DataFrame([
    [2,2,3,4,5],
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,2,3,4,5],
    [7,2,3,4,5]

], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])


dict_result = call_data.set_index('A').to_dict(orient='index')

for k, v in dict_result.items():
    print(k, v)

2 {'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5}
1 {'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5}
6 {'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5}
7 {'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5}
```

In case you want to look for another format you can see more options by putting:

```
print(help(call_data.to_dict))
```

Where you can see more detail:

```
  Parameters
    ----------
    orient : str {'dict', 'list', 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index'}
        Determines the type of the values of the dictionary.
    
        - 'dict' (default) : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
        - 'list' : dict like {column -> [values]}
        - 'series' : dict like {column -> Series(values)}
        - 'split' : dict like
          {'index' -> [index], 'columns' -> [columns], 'data' -> [values]}
        - 'records' : list like
          [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]
        - 'index' : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
```

Comment: Just beware that this will throw an error if you A column is not unique.

Comment: I edited my code above but I don' t think I did it right as I get this error:       
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Personal Files/Technical Development/PycharmProjects/Call Center Headcount Model/Call Center Headcount Model.py", line 50, in <module>
    call_data.index('A').to_dict(orient='index')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: You might want to post the error message that you have got

Comment: try ```set_index('A')``` instead of just ```index('A')```

Comment: Edited my og post

Comment: Hello, simply try directly and tell us what error you get :  dict_result = call_data.set_index('A').to_dict(orient='index')

Comment: I edited my post to show the error I am getting and how I formatted the code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just making sure one more thing ```call_data = CallData.to_dict()```. What is the content of ```CallData```? And why do you put ```to_dict``` into that?

Comment: andondraif, I edited my post to show what CallData is, which it is an excel worksheet. I was making call_data a dictionary and then 'orienting' it in the next line, should I remove that?

Comment: I was able to edit my answer to give you an example